# SQL Server. How do i round a decimal considering all decimal digits

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

I'm trying to round a decimal and it seems like rounding in SQL Server only considers one digit after the last digit of rounding scale.

```
SELECT CAST(795.5921967249997 AS decimal(18,8))
--795.59219672
SELECT ROUND(795.5921967249997, 8)
--795.5921967200000
```

What I'm looking for is a fair rounding, that considers all digits. In example above I'm expecting 3 as 8-th decimal digit.
Can I do this without writing my own function?

Comment: "SQL Server only considers one digit after the last digit of rounding scale" - that is how rounding is usually done. If you want to establish your own non-standard roundig-rules you'll have to implement them yourselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want "3" in that position, then you are changing the rules of rounding.  You can do this in two steps:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(795.5921967249997 AS decimal(18, 9)) as decimal(18, 8))
```